# How to build zend 2 forms automatically from doctrine 2 entity-classes?

Tags: php, cakephp, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

Is there a way to automatically build a zend framework form by having a doctrine 2 entity-class?

Important Information: ***This is only a example and no productive setup.***
E.g.

Users (Entity) class:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Users
 */
class Users
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

Users xml mapping definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
  <entity name="Users" table="users">
    <id name="id" type="integer" column="ID">
      <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
    </id>
    <field name="name" type="string" column="name" length="50" nullable="true"/>
  </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

Now i would like to have a zend 2 form class, where i can inject this entity and the form itself builds a basic form and attaches validators to this form. Here in this example it would atach a StringLenght validator (max 50; see xml mapping above) to the users field.

Something like this is possible like i know in CakePHP. I would be really happy to have such feature in Zend framework 2, too;-)

For now i found one link: http://www.lewanscheck.de/2013/09/21/inject-doctrine-orm-entitymanager-in-zf2-form/ but no automatic creation of validation from the xml file.

Would be great to implement only a model/entity class with a xml/yml/annotation(even when i do not like annotations) configuration and build automatically a db schema-part (this works with doctrine 2) and a form class.

Comment: You can [use annotations](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html#using-annotations) to build the form

Comment: thx Alex, but i do not like the idea of annotations, is there a generic FormBuilder that can build formsb by injecting the model to it? I do not want to configure it on my own using annotations, i would like to have it done automatically;-)